# Cost of an algorithm

Tags: c++, algorithm, performance

The problem is the next:

We want to know the size of an vector, we can't use size() but we have a function **inBounds(vector& arr,int index)** that returns true if the index is a valid position of the vector.

So, my approach is iterate positions. Starting at 1 and duplicating (2,4,8,16,32...) until that inBounds returns false, step back so and repeat the search in the subrange.

Let's do an example, put N = 21:

- 1 = True
- 2 = True
- 4 = True
- 8 = True
- 16 = True
- 32 = False

Step back to 16, and search in 16-32 range:

- (16+1) = True
- (16+2) = True
- (16+4) = True
- (16+8) = False

Step back to 20 (16+4) and start over:

- (20+1) = True
- (20+2) = False

Start over in 21:

- (21+1) = False

Ok, so the size is 21.

This is my implementation in code:

```
#include <iostream>
#include <vector>
using namespace std;

int inBounds(const vector<int>& arr,int i)
{
    return i < arr.size();
}

int size(const vector<int>& arr)
{
    int init = 0;

    while (inBounds(arr,init))
    {
        int start = 2;
        while (inBounds(arr,init+start))
        {
            start *= 2;
        }
        start /= 2;
        init += start;
    }
    return init;
}


int main()
{
    vector<int> arr;

    for (int i = 0;i < 1000;i++)
    {
        arr.resize(i);
        int n = size(arr);
        if (n != arr.size())
            cout << "FAIL " << arr.size() << ' ' << n << endl;
    }
    return 0;
}
```

This works good. But i don't know the exactly cost of this algorithm. The first search is indeed log(N), but now i need to add the subrange searchs. So i have my doubts about the real cost

Comment: That's a strange way to do it. I'd go with the doubling in a top level first cycle to determine the upper bound. Then, in also a top level cycle, you go with [binary search](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Binary_search_algorithm). All in all, you will have` 2 x O(log(N)) = O(log(N))`

Comment: Your algo's complexity is O(log * log). See my answer

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Actually, your worst case scenario is **O(log(n)<sup>2</sup>)** (which is sorta expected, since you have a `O(log)` cycle nested inside another log cycle)

To understand why, try to narrow down 31 (2<sup>N</sup>-1 in the general case)

Let's do an example, put N = 31:

```
1 = True
2 = True
4 = True
8 = True
16 = True
32 = False
```

O(log(N)) to here, alright, nobody contests it

--

Now count the extra steps

Step back to 16, and search in 16-32 range:

```
(16+1) = True
(16+2) = True
(16+4) = True
(16+8) = True
(16+16) = False
```

(4+1) steps - which is log(32/2)+1 = log(32)

Step back at 24

```
(24+1) = True
(24+2) = True
(24+4) = True
(24+8) = False
```

(3+1) steps - which is log(16/2)+1=log(16)

Step back at 28:

```
(28+1) = True
(28+2) = True
(28+4) = False
```

(2+1) steps - which is log(8/2)+1=log(8)

Step back at 30

```
(30+1) = True
(30+2) = False
```

(1+1) steps which is log(4/2)+1=log(4)

Result: (4+3+2+1=10 steps in positive + 4 in negative). Or, in another form `log(32)+log(16)+log(8)+log(4)+log(2) - 1 =log(32)(1+1/2+1/3+1/4+1/5)-1`. Ignore the -1 at the end and your formula becomes something like

`log(N)*(1+1/2+1/3+1/4+...+1/N)`

Well, for large N-es, the [harmonic series](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Harmonic_series_(mathematics)) is divergent and the asymptotic behaviour is [logarithmic](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Harmonic_series_(mathematics)#Rate_of_divergence).

So you got yourself a nice `O(log(N)*log(N))` complexity.

QED(??)

Answer (score 1):

seems like your first subrange search is also logN (since it uses basically same algorithm as the initial part) while your final subrange search is linear (iterating over every value), but it's very much bounded and a small fraction of N.  i would say your algorithm is roughly c * logN, where c is a small value representing the number of subsearches you're doing, so O(logN) in general.

Comment: Techincaly, the first subrange size is exactly N/2. How many subsearchs would need in N/2? This is the question.

Comment: @amchacon true, the 1st subrange size is N/2, but the search algorithm in that subrange is the same as in the first, is it not? you said the cost in the first search is logN, so in the 1st subrange search, it should be logN/2 as you correctly noted. if you have O(logN + logN/2), the O(logN) term still dominates as N increases.

Comment: yeah, that sounds right. I think that has a constant multiplier by the sub-sums, but in Big O dominates Log(N)

Comment: @melgart " is roughly c * logN " Wrong answer: it's actually O(log * log)

Answer (score 1):

Once you've found the upper bound, you really should do a binary search. Applying to your example:

- Result of initial loop: 16 → true, 32 → false, so size in (16, 32]

The binary search always tests the middle between the largest found true and the smallest found false:

- 24 → false => (16, 24]
- 20 – true => (20, 24]
- 22 → false => (20, 22]
- 21 → false => (20, 21]

So the size is 21.

Note that this needed only 4 additional tests, as opposed to 7 for your algorithm.

Comment: definitely useful info, but OP is asking for the _cost_ of his algorithm.

Comment: @melgart [XY problem](http://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/66377/what-is-the-xy-problem).

Answer (score 1):

Suppose the size of the vector is N = 31. Since this is going to be the worst case for the your algorithm here is how it will work:

```
first pass : 1,2,4,8,16,32            [ total = 6 ]
second pass: 17,18,20,24,32           [ total = 5 ]
third pass : 25,26,28,32              [ total = 4 ]
forth pass : 29,30,32                 [ total = 3 ]
fifth pass : 31                       [ total = 1 ]
```

If we talk in terms on N. it would be:

```
T(N) = logN*(1+1/2+1/4+1/8+....)
```

which is of order: `(logN)^2`

You should actually consider the approach given by @celtschk which is `O(logN)`